# AngularJS and nodeJs Express: routes and refresh

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, routes

My app is "working" fine, but, when I press F5 in browser my problem appears.

My app is organized this way:

nodeJs + express, in Express I have those routes

```
core.app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index')
});

core.app.get('/partials/:name', function(req, res){
    nome = req.params.name
    res.render('partials/' + name)
});

core.app.get('/partials/:folder/:name', function(req, res){
    name = req.params.name
    pasta = req.params.folder
    res.render('partials/' + folder + '/' + name)
});
```

route for service

```
core.app.post('/servico/usuario/buscar', function(req, res){
    console.log('servico.usuario.buscar');

    console.log(req.body);

    model.buscar(core, req.body.termo, function(status, data){
        if(status == core.Status.error){
            console.error("Erro na busca de usuário!")
            console.error("termo: " + req.body.termo);
        }
        res.json(data);
    })
})
```

in my angularJs i have those routes

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/index'})
        .when('/enviar/busca/usuarios', {templateUrl: '/partials/usuario/lista_usuario', reloadOnSearch: true})
        .when('/enviar/busca/produto', {templateUrl: '/partials/produto/listar', controller: 'BuscaProduto'})
}]);
```

my form

```
form#form1(name='formBuscaTopo', method='post', novalidate)
    span.L
        input(name='tipoBuscaTopo', type='radio', value="p", data-ng-model="busca.tipoBusca")
        label(for='produtos') produtos
        input(name='tipoBuscaTopo', type='radio', value="u", data-ng-model="busca.tipoBusca")
        label(for='produtos') usuários

    input#busca_geral.busca_campo(type='text', name='termo', data-ng-model="busca.termo", placeholder='faça aqui a sua busca')

    #lupa
        img(src='/images/base/lupa.png', alt='Buscar', title='Buscar', data-ng-click="buscar()")
```

and in my angular controller

```
http.post('/servico/usuario/buscar', scope.busca)
        .success(function(data){
            scope.listaUsuario = data;
            location.path('/enviar/busca/usuarios');
        })
```

and my list view

```
    div.box_busca_usu.c_azlEsc(data-ng-repeat="item in listaUsuario")
    div.busca_img_usu
        img.img75(data-ng-src="/img/avatar/gd/{{item.usuario.foto}}")
    div.box_d_u
        div.busca_n_usu.txt_14 {{item.usuario.nome}}
        img.img16(src='/img/status/superUsuario.png', title='usuário rubi', alt='usuário rubi')
        .HW100L.top5
            span {{item.usuario.cidade}}
            |/
            span {{item.usuario.estado}}
        .HW100L.txt_11.c_666.top5 Cadastrado desde
            span.c_azlEsc.lft5 {{item.usuario.dataCadastro}}
```

all is working fine, and the response is printed perfectly, but, if I press F5 I receive  the message 'Cannot GET /enviar/busca/usuarios'.

I think the problem is because there is no route for '/enviar/busca/usuarios' in my express, that is set in angular $location.path in the last step, but, if I set this route in express routes, the problem change, because refresh don't send the original form values (parameters), so, my express return an error message, because don't have any term to search.

Is there some sugestion to solve my problem?

thanks for attention,

Comment: Why do you need serverside routes?

Comment: because all my services (containing rules, access database, etc.) will be in serverside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this properly you need to make sure that any virtual (e.g. route) requests to your Express app will respond with the 'index' view.

You should be able to accomplish this by re-ordering your Express routes and using '*' to catch all requests besides those for '/partials/...' etc.  As long as your '/partials/....' routes don't call next() you should be good.

```
core.app.get('/partials/:name', function(req, res){
    nome = req.params.name
    res.render('partials/' + name)
});

core.app.get('/partials/:folder/:name', function(req, res){
    name = req.params.name
    pasta = req.params.folder
    res.render('partials/' + folder + '/' + name)
});

core.app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.render('index')
});
```

Comment: Hi Roy,

First, thanks for your attention,

I put the route suggested, and now the browser render the index, but my ng-view didn't  reload, Do I need to put some thing to angularJs resend the parameters sent in original request?

Comment: In addition, this is very helpfull, http://stackoverflow.com/a/14168882, and help to understand what's happening

Answer (score -1):

Remove method='POST' from #form1