# .htaccess on heroku for angularjs app

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs, heroku

I have deployed an AngularJS app built with lineman using lineman-angular template on heroku.
Html5 mode is enabled and I would like to fix the “Page not found” issue on page refresh.

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found) I can see that it is possible to add rules into .htaccess file.

So I created the file with the following content:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css¦js|html|png)
  RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</ifModule>
```

If I place the .htaccess file in the root of my app, then my app stops working and I can  see the following error:

```
Internal Server Error 
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
```

I am puzzled where I need to create the .htaccess file on heroku cedar app.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: Did you get this solved?

Comment: I've used the Hashbang mode instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a while I decided to revisit this problem, e.g. configuring the server side for deployed on Heroku Angular.js app with Html5 mode enabled, which was built using Lineman.js.

I’ve checked the [heroku-buildpack-lineman](https://github.com/linemanjs/heroku-buildpack-lineman) and found the updated information, that there probably no need for the custom build pack.
So I followed their instructions to configure the official Node.js buildpack:

```
$ heroku config:set BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs 
$ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

Then included a Procfile:

```
web: npm run production
```

And finally added their production script:

```
"scripts": {     
  "start": "lineman run",     
  "test": "lineman spec-ci",       
  "production": "lineman clean build && npm i express@3 && node -e \"var e = require('express'), a = e(); a.use(e.static('dist/')); a.listen(process.env.PORT)\""   
},
```

But I also included the express rewrite code into production script using a catch all route middleware.

Below is the modified production script:

```
"production": "lineman clean build && npm i express@3 && node -e \"var e = require('express'), a = e(); a.use(e.static('dist/')); a.use(function(req, res) { res.sendfile('dist/index.html'); }); a.listen(process.env.PORT)\""
```

Now the app deployed on Heroku works as I needed!

Comment: I am also facing the same problem, can you please provide more details on how to solve this , I am abit confused about this solution.

Comment: @MiladRk Insert the above "scripts" snippet into your package.json. Then your app will be running with node express that is configured to handle route redirects (see the "production" line).