# AngularJS page not working when refresh/share a link

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess

I have a webpage and it's working just fine. The problem starts when i need to refresh the page or try to share a link with someone (or even open it in a new tab).

When i try to do it, the page doesn't work. It loads only the header, footer, etc. But not the part inside my `ng-view` and also no css class, etc...

Also, I'm using html5 mode in AngularJS with this code:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled:true
});
```

I tried to use a .htaccess to reload the page and it's working, but only for the first link. For example `site.com/News` is loading ok, but if I try to refresh/share the page `site.com/News/4` (which goes to an individual news page) then it won't work anymore.

This is the code i used in my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)       /index.html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Comment: Now i'm getting an error when i try to refresh any page. `The requested URL /index.html/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: It's working fine on the link, but when i need to open an individual news, for example, by it's own `id` "site.com/news/23" then it doesn't work.