# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found AngularJS with IIS

Tags: angularjs, iis, gulp

I have used gulp to build my client angularJS application. After i deployed into IIS i'm getting an issue. My page is working fine when navigate through menu's. But when i refresh by page (or) copy and paste the URL its giving me 404 error.
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
can anyone help me, to resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

> Use the `otherwise` method, which is the default route when none of the others get a match

---

Did you configured `otherwise` option in your route config section?

like this below?

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider.otherwise({
             templateUrl : "main.htm",
             controller : "mainController"
        });
});
```

You can test it under this link

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing_otherwise

I hope you can solve your issue by this below discussion

[Refreshing page gives "Page not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found)

Comment: i don't have any issue navigation through menu, meaning i have a route. also i have configured otherwise route as well.

Comment: @Velkumar did you try `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);` ? in your route config

Comment: yes now its working fine. Thank you
But do you know how to remove # from URL?