# Angularjs get error 404 while page refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I refresh page getting error 404-page not found.

Index file

```
 <base href="/Rushi/sandwichesuk/"/>
```

App.js

```
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
  .when('/index1', {
       templateUrl: 'assets/views/index1.html',
       controller: 'index1Controller'
    })
```

this is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ Rushi/sandwichesuk/index.html [L]
```

error:

[image]

Comment: Possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168836/refreshing-page-gives-page-not-found

Comment: @PareshGami it's not duplicate because of already tried this solution and get  same error btw thx for the response

Comment: That seems AngularJS project?

Comment: @PareshGami yes, but what you think it's angular or not..

Comment: check your htaccess working well. 
If yes make sure you gave the base tag before calling any urls.

Comment: @Golwin thx for the response but how can I check .htaccess file is working or not any idea?

Comment: @Rushidave just type anything at the start of .htaccess file and reload the page. If the page shows internal server error then, htaccess is working fine.

Comment: @Golwin .htaccess file not working what I do file work fine

Comment: go through the steps in any of the following links
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingUseOfApacheHtaccessFiles
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184380/discussion-between-rushi-dave-and-golwin).

Comment: @Golwin i m using windows and then I tried .htaceess file working or not after many tried it's not working and I have a question .htaccess file required or not? and  thx for your response

Comment: so you are using windows system right? I hope its localhost. please let me know the server that you are using. apache or node.

Comment: @Golwin i m using Apache server

Comment: are you using any development servers linke xamp or wamp. I think those have different configurations to make the htaccess to work

Comment: I m using xampp sever

Comment: @Golwin When I am refreshing page get a new error. LIKE: Internal Server Error

Comment: @Golwin i solved my problem and big thank you for your response and also  given time thx again

Comment: @Rushidave welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my question

Refrence https://lancelhoff.com/enabling-htaccess-in-apache-on-windows/

and also changes  .htaccess file

```
 RewriteEngine on
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
 RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
 RewriteRule ^ - [L] 
 RewriteRule ^ /Rushi/sandwichesuk/index.html
```